# Выполнение процедуры по наименованию, задаваемому переменной

Tags: android

Доброго времени суток!
Необходимо реализовать в сервисе выполнение определенных процедур при передаче их наименований в intent для BroadcastReceiver. То есть, сервису передается intent вида:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(<Наименование акции>);
intent.putExtra("operation", <Наименование процедуры>);
```

Сервис, в свою очередь, на основании переданной "operation" выполняет необходимую функцию.

Хотелось бы знать, есть ли какой-либо другой вариант, кроме if(operation.equals(<Наименование процедуры>){<Выполнение нужной процедуры>} и как его реализовать.

Comment: Хороший вопрос. На C# можно было бы завести `Dictionary<string, Action>`.

Comment: Но с другой стороны, зачем так? Почему к вам приходит обезличенная строка, а не «живой» объект?

Comment: то есть switch(opeartion) { case ID_OPERATION1:  funcOp1(); break; case ID_OPERATION_N: funcopN();break;   } , не катит ?

Comment: >Но с другой стороны, зачем так? Почему к вам приходит обезличенная строка, а не «живой» объект? Потому что intent. Как в intente передать живой объект ?

Comment: В данном случае идет обмен команд между интерфейсом и сервисом. Интерфейс выдает команду, сервис ее исполняет и отдает ответ. Передачи каких либо живых объектов не требуется.

Comment: И опять же, гугл знает все. Ответ по первой ссылке. https://www.google.com.ua/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&es_th=1&ie=UTF-8#q=java%20call%20method%20by%20name&es_th=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Да без проблем иcпользуйте java.lang.reflect.Method
У меня было примерно так реализовано в одном проекте.

```
 import java.lang.reflect.Method;

 public class ReflectAction {

 public void startAction(String methodName, long arg1) {
         Method method;
         try {
              method = this.getClass().getDeclaredMethod(methodName,long.class);
            } catch (SecurityException e) {
              // ...
            } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
              // ...                
                Log.d("MyLogs", " no Such Method");
            }

         try {
              method.invoke(this, arg1);
            } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {             
            }        
     }

     public void function1(long arg1) {
     }

     public void function2(long agr1) {
     }

     public void function3(long arg3) {
     }   
     }
```

Comment: Спасибо, завтра попробую реализовать.

Comment: Еще раз спасибо. Это как раз то, что было нужно